# help req in basic t-sql

Tags: t-sql

Below is a table.

```
 stu_id   meet_doc_id   doc_name   stu_name       dob           value      date
    101        0104          AD          AM      15/06/1950     LMDO     2011-02-15
    101        0105          AD          AM      15/06/1950     CLEAR    2011-02-18
    101        0106          AD          AM      15/06/1950     CLEAR    2011-02-25
    102        0107          AD          AK      12/08/1987     CLEAR    2011-03-28
    102        0108          AD          AK      12/08/1987     LDMO     2011-04-29
    103        0109          PK          LMP     13/07/1970     CLEAR    2011-03-28
    103        0110          PK          LMP     13/07/1970     CLEAR    2011-05-12
```

What will be the resulting query if I expect to see a result set of

```
  stu_id    meet_doc_id   doc_name   stu_name      dob          value      date
    101        0104          AD          AM      15/06/1950     LMDO     2011-02-15
    102        0107          AD          AK      12/08/1987     CLEAR    2011-03-28
    103        0110          PK          LMP     13/07/1970     CLEAR    2011-05-12
```

Comment: What logic did you use to get to your expected results? This is fairly unclear.

Comment: Depends on the query! Perhaps a little more thought into the question.

Comment: @Matt - Looks like they want the first row for each `stu_id` group as ordered by `meet_doc_id`

Comment: Maybe. palum posted something a little earlier that was nearly as cryptic. The earlier post had something to do with the value, but now it looks like it all has been changed.

Comment: All i need to find is the student which has a value LMDO for that paticular doctor. If there is no LMDO present then it should show CLEAR.

Comment: Looks a lot like the previous post to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table looks extremely un-normalised with lots of repeating groups but I think you need

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT stu_id,
                meet_doc_id,
                doc_name,
                stu_name,
                dob,
                value,
                date,
                ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY stu_id ORDER BY meet_doc_id) AS
                RN
         FROM   YourTable)
select stu_id,
       meet_doc_id,
       doc_name,
       stu_name,
       dob,
       value,
       date
FROM   CTE
WHERE  RN = 1
```

Comment: Martin if you look at my previous question on CTE. you will understand it. Its not a table its the resultset of a query in CTE.